# Does merging separate PDFs reduce the overall size of the file?

Tags: pdf, merge, compression, size

I have a number of individual PDF files, that are mainly composed of text and a few images (most of these images are repeated in the files).

I need to send all these files at a regular frequency and as such need to reduce file size. Zipping doesn't make much of a difference, however I have been advised that merging the file can significantly reduce the file size.

Can anyone here confirm whether this is possible and if so how much of a reduction is possible?

I can provide more clarification if needed?

Comment: It depends on the intelligence of the merging software/library/code you can use, and on how easy the fact that images are shared is detectable in your PDFs. Thus, please supply sample PDFs and some information on your environment: Do you send the files manually and want some ready made tool for merging? Do you have some automatic third-party sending server the merging routine would have to be integrated into? Do you have implemented your own sending service and can integrate any merging solution you want?